# How do i stop GIF at certain frame and get the output in JPG in imagick PHP?

Tags: php, image, imagick

Hello I am using imagick to morph two images but i am getting the output as GIF with n number of frames. Here is the code

```
    morphImages();

    function morphImages()
    {
    $images = [

    "1.png",
    "2.png",

    ];

    $imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($images[count($images) - 1]));

    foreach ($images as $image) {
       $nextImage = new \Imagick(realpath($image));
       $imagick->addImage($nextImage);
    }

    $imagick->resetIterator();

    $morphed = $imagick->morphImages(25);

    header("Content-Type: image/gif");

    $morphed->setImageFormat('gif');

    echo $morphed->getImagesBlob();
    }
```

The output i'm getting is this - http://applekaka.com/test.php

Now i want the output as JPEG at 13th frame, How do i do that?

Comment: A motion gif cannot contain a jpeg image.

Comment: http://applekaka.com/test.php the output is here, are sure no way?